# Failed runs missing from My Executions list

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that does some GMail inbox cleanup. It is executed by a trigger every 5 minutes. It runs fine most of the time, the failure rate is 0.8%. However some of the executions don't show as Completed or Failed. They just don't show up under the **My Executions** list at all.

I set up to get a daily summary email which show that some runs are being canceled with reason "Service using too much computer time for one day". However this is completely random with executions immediately before and after completing successfully. If a particular executions did take too long and was cancelled why doesn't it show that in the **My Executions** list? How can I get more detail about these aborted executions?

I checked the documentation and it says I am likely hitting some quota limit. However, I don't know specifically which quota because the aborted executions are not displayed or reported in the App Script Dashboard.

Comment: Show the script with execution transcript found in `View > Execution transcript`, then we'll be able to see what's taking it so long to execute and hopefully be able to reduce the time taken.

Comment: "Service using too much computer time for one day" indicates that the total quota limit per day per account is reached which is 360 minutes. you can increase the delay between trigger timings to avoid this.

Comment: Just following up, I tried to reduce the time to execute by doing less work with each run and I also followed your advice and increased the interval between runs to 30 minutes. This has reduced the error rate to zero. It seems that the script engine is just a little slower than I expected when it comes to processing gmail email.